# How to control the Cross-range of a scene for a fixed resolution in SAR image processing?

Tags: radar

In order to image a scene with a certain resolution I would have to fly a certain distance. The longer the flight, the better the azimuth resolution. This is determined by the following formula

$$\rho_a=\frac{\lambda_c R}{2L}$$

Where $\rho_a$ is the azimuth resolution, $\lambda_c$ is the wavelength, $R$ is the distance to target and $L$ is the synthetic aperture length.

The doppler frequency of a scatter can be computed as such,
$$f_d = \frac{2V_a cos(\alpha_d)}{\lambda_c}$$

where $V_a$ is the radar's velocity, $\alpha_d$ is the cone angle relative to the radar's velocity

By flying a certain length, I would be able to determine the azimuth resolution of my image.
I want to only process a certain arbitrary cross-range width. By limiting the Doppler frequency I am processing does this automatically translate to the desired cross-range width? If so how can the arbitrary cross-range width I desire be obtained? Otherwise, what is correct way of obtaining the arbitrary cross-range width?

If you could point me to references on controlling azimuth scene width, that would be great!

Comment: To control the size of the image in cross-range, you would downsample the data in the cross-range frequency dimension. Either that, or just cut the section of the image that you want. Less FLOPs to do it the other way though.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 I wanted to perform a sub-aperture stitching operation on different sub-apertures. Will this suggestion work for the sub-aperture stitching? I can post this as another question if there are a lot of details involved in the explanation

Comment: Either one will, but if you want to preserve phase continuity across the patches, you have to do it carefully. If you only care about magnitude, then it doesn't matter.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 Thank you for the tips!